# Indenting code blocks using a Swedish keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

The shortcut for indenting a block of code is usually ⌘], which I cannot do on a Swedish keyboard.
Does anyone know any workarounds?

I'm not looking for a solution for any specific editor but a way of triggering this shortcut.

Comment: cmd+alt+9 to indent or respectively cmd+alt+8 to unindent doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work on nitrous.io but works in the other ones that I'm using, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. Press alt, command and 9.